Dynamic median calculation - Postgresql
I have issues building superset chart.
I have a table like this:



vac_start_date
vac_brand_name
executor_id
shifts




2024-09-09
LPP
375
21


2024-09-09
LPP
376
2


2024-09-09
LPP
377
1


2024-09-09
DMC
375
2


2024-09-09
DMC
373
1


2024-09-09
DMC
378
5


2024-09-09
DMC
379
4


2024-09-09
v
375
8


2024-09-09
v
377
7


2024-09-09
v
380
6


2024-09-09
v
321
5



select vac_start_date
   , vac_brand_name
   , percentile_cont(.5) within group(order by shifts)
from workt2
group by vac_start_date, vac_brand_name

This code gives me median amount of shifts within groups of brand names.
My goal: I want to count the median in total and different slices as well, regulated by filter 'vac_brand_name' set.
So, when I don't filter this table by brand_name, I'd like to get this output:



vac_start_date
median_shifts




2024-09-09
5



Because I've sum up all shifts by executor_id and got the median out of it.
But when I filter the chart by brand, for example 'dmc', I'd rather get the value 3



vac_start_date
vac_brand_name
median_shifts




2024-09-09
dmc
3



And so on, when I select brands dmc and v, I sum up the shifts by executor_id as in the first case - but only having 2 brands. Result is 5



vac_start_date
vac_brand_name
median_shifts




2024-09-09
dmc, v
5



Is there any way to get such a dynamic median value in Apache Superset?
